# Outlook with existing data files

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, pop3, pst

I reinstalled my computer and I did a back up of the Outlook pst data files. Now I installed Outlook and added my email account. I told it to use the existing data file.

Then it started to download the messages. It downloaded the same messages from the server again!

I use POP3 but I have set it to keep the messages on the server, because I have multiple computers so I need to access the messages everywhere. I don't want to use IMAP, because then it requires an Internet connection to get the emails.

How to get it working?

Comment: While I realize the accepted answer goes against your not wanting to use IMAP, it's still the same question.  You may want to consider commenting, and placing a Bounty, on the existing question to get more/different answers

Answer (score 1):

POP3 doesn't do a check to see what messages you already have. IMAP does though:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/force-outlook-2007-to-download-complete-imap-items/

If you still want to use POP3 you can try something like this (setting the date of when POP3 should begin from on your webmail server):
http://www.msoutlook.info/question/227

If you don't have the option to tell POP3 what date to "start" downloading, then you will have to let it all download again, unless someone else has a trick or tool to have outlook check against existing messages.

Comment: @MikkoP Which webmail service is providing the email address? Gmail? The answer above is on the right track and I think you'll be able to find a solution in the webmail service's settings.